# How do I solve this "Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.0.M5"

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, pom.xml, artifact

am getting this error in my pom.xml file

> Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.0.0.M5

How do I solve this can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

The first answer is the correct one. you have to add the following repository to ur pom file.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 4):

To resolve this probleme you need to add the right repository to your pom.xml

```
<repositories><repository><id>spring-milestone</id><name>Spring Milestone Repository</name><url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url></repository></repositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is maven was not able to download the jar. TO resolve this first locate your .m2 directory and traverse to org -springframework and delete the folder spring-core and then from your eclipse right click on the pom.xml and click on update project. It will again download the required dependency.